# Trello How do I find all the cards "Archived" when on a particular List?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I'd like to find all the Archived cards from a given list.    I'm fine with using the web site or using the Trello API.

Comment: To search for a particular archived card, click on **Show Menu** (top right) >  **More** > **Archived Items**. Credits to Google and [archive-unarchive-trello-how-to](https://rewind.com/blog/archive-unarchive-trello-how-to/#:~:text=To%20view%20a%20card%20you,ve%20archived%20on%20that%20board.)

Answer (score 31):

I realize this is an old question but I could not comment on the top answer due to shortage of reputation.

Currently it is possible—see http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1145462-searching-for-cards-all-boards- for more information. Trello searches across boards so it will find all the archived cards in all the lists with the specified name.

Enter this in the search box: `is:archived list:Done`

Comment: Comments are comments and you gave an answer

Comment: is:archived is a good workaround

Answer (score 2):

This may not currently be possible.  Note the limitation here:

http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1145462-searching-for-cards-all-boards-

"Trello search currently only searches cards and names of boards. It **does not currently search checklist items or list names**."

You can easily search for archived by just adding 'is:archived' to the search.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using the API. See here:

https://trello.com/docs/api/list/index.html

For example, from the Trello dev board:

```
curl https://api.trello.com/1/lists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000001d?cards=closed&card_fields=name
```

(Check out [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) for a nicer experience)

To get the id of the list, either use the API or do it the poor man's way: entering something like this in the JS console with the relevant board open:

```
_.map(ModelCache._cache.List, function(value, key) { return {id: key, name: value.get('name')}; })[0]
```

That only works because the Trello Dev board is public. To get data from a private board, follow the instructions here:

https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/index.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the Trello API documentation, possible options for `filter` are `all`, `closed`, `none`, `open and` visible`. So to get all archived cards, do:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/{board}/cards?filter=closed&key={key}&token={token}
```

For all cards, both archived and unarchived:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/{board}/cards?filter=all&key={key}&token={token}
```

You can then filter the result on a list ID.